# GraphQL - handle nested data

Tags: graphql

My data schema is as:

```
{
    instrumentName: String,
    lastPrice {
        bid: Float,
        ask: Float
    }
}
```

The data is stored, for example in Json format, in my database like:

```
{
    "instrumentName": "GOOGLE.N",
    "lastPrice": {
        "bid": 90.00,
        "ask": 105.00
    }
}
```

In GraphQL, I have to define the graphQL schema as:

```
type Instrument {
    instrumentName: String
    lastPrice: Price
}
type Price {
    bid: Float
    ask: Float
}
```

When I build my data fetchers, the Instrument fetcher is fine. I just pick the record from the database as the previous sample data.
But when it recursively fetch the Price, as the bid/ask prices are already load from database in the Instrument fetcher, I'm wondering is there a way to "tell" the Price fetcher about the previous sample data, for example, put the data into the data fetching environment of the Price fetcher?
Or can I define a different (nested) graphQL schema to handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presently using apollo-server and with this at least (don't know about other GraphQL implementations off-hand), the [default resolver behaviour](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/#default-resolver) should take care of this for you, so there would be only one database fetch needed, provided your `instrument` fetcher returns the full data structure:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        instrument: (parent, args, context, info) => {
            instrumentName: "GOOGLE.N",
            lastPrice: {
                bid: 90.00,
                ask: 105.00
            }                    
        }
    },

    // Following resolver should not be needed as will be handled by default resolver
    //  Instrument: {
    //      lastPrice: (parent, args, context, info) => {
    //          ...
    //      }
    //  }
}
```

If you are using something other than apollo-server, I'm not certain if the above holds.

Comment: I'm using GraphQL-java. And finally I found all things could be described as Map<String, Object> recursively. So it works now. Thank you John :)